# How to get user details from facebook after creating app id using php

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, xampp

I need to include facebook login on my website for registration purpose. I have created a facebook app and logged in. I am getting only prfile name and userid from facebook. How can I get the email and other user informations from facebook?

These are the records I am getting from facebook:

Array ( [name] => facebook User [id] => 92141138733449309036 )

```
<?php
    require 'src/facebook.php';
    $db = file_get_contents('../../../Bin/Configuration.php');
    $exp_db = array();
    $exp_db = explode('\'',$db);
    // print_r($exp_db);
    // exit;

    $hostname = $exp_db[1];
    $username = $exp_db[3];
    $password = $exp_db[5];
    $database = $exp_db[7];

    $connect = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($database,$connect) or die(mysql_error());


    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      // 'appId'  => $recordFB['fb_application_id'],
      // 'secret' => $recordFB['fb_application_secret'],
      'appId'  => '1699756843642082',
      'secret' => 'a8aab00a1e1a5bdcdd9d4665c0972637',

      'cookie' => true,
    ));

    // Get User ID
    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    // We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
    //
    // If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
    // Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
    // token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

    if ($user) {
      try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      echo "You are NOT Logged in";
    }

    if (!$user_profile) {
      $loginUrl=$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('canvas'=>1,
                                             'fbconnect' => 0,
                                    'req_perms'=> 'email,user_birthday ,publish_stream',
                                          'next' => CANVAS_PAGE,
                                          'cancel_url' => CANVAS_PAGE));
      echo '<fb:redirect url="' . $loginUrl . '" />';
      # code...
    }else
    {
      echo "you can use this app";
    }

    $email=$user_profile['email'];
?>
```

I can't get other details from facebook. Please tell me the possible solution for accessing user details from facebook... Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get facebook profile details usring script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35224773/how-to-get-facebook-profile-details-usring-script)

Answer (score 0):

Search for "Declarative Fields" in the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

Without specifying the fields you want to get, you will only get the ID and name.